# Git отправка веток

Tags: git

Нужно отправить ветку develop в которой находиться на данный момент (Ну просто рабочая версия проекта!) 
В мастере пустой проект (просто созданный проект, чистый).

Можно ли отправить ветку develop? что бы у того кому я скину ссылку (git clone URL.............), клонировалась те файлы которые находятся в ветке deveop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попросту укажите ветку в git clone, указав при этом флаг `--single-branch`:

```
git clone --single-branch -b develop *url*
```

Без указания флага `--single-branch`, git скачает все ветки.

Comment: Работает Спасибо!!!